# How to modularize/share code between multiple iOS Swift apps?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

So, I'm starting a 3rd or 4th in house iOS app today. They're all Swift4 using the latest version of Xcode. I have a big group of "Extensions" that I end up copying from project to project. This doesn't really scale.

I'd like to learn how one decomposes "support" code into a separate project/module.

What is the basic roadmap (for a novice developer) to extract common code between 2 or more apps and manage that in a separate repository/module/package?

As a simple example, let's say I just really like this little extension:

```
// I like my print's to look like message sends instead of global free functions 
extension String {
    func print() {
        Swift.print(self)
    }
}
```

Do I create a separate project for it? What kind? `Cocoa Touch Framework`, `Cocoa Touch Static Library`, or something else (maybe `Cross-platform: Empty`?)? Are there some other boilerplate settings I need to apply to the project?

Once I have that compiling, how do I "include" it in my end user apps?

Comment: Usually, a project for these third party code. (event if it's yours). You can after use Carthage or CocoaPods for that. That's not a bad idea.

Comment: You can import the project as module or framework and can embed inside

Answer (score 0):

For iOS Apps, I guess the easiest solution is to use cocoaPods. 
Try [this](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html)

For some non-iOS libraries, try swift package [manager](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/tree/master/Documentation)